# CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> Status Code Expectations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, completable-future, spring-cloud-contract

So, I have created a Controller within which I have a POST endpoint like so:

```
@PostMapping("/foo/{some-field}")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> foo() {
    //Do some operations...
    ...
    if(doesNotExist({some-field})) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.ok().build());
}
```

Now I would expect that if `doesNotExist({some-field}) == true`, I'd be prompted with a `NOT_FOUND` status.
I however end up with a `OK` status every time around.

Are my expectations wrong in regards to how the `ResponseEntity` is returned?
Any suggestions how to get the `NOT_FOUND` status if `doesNotExist({some-field}) == true` would be much appreciated.

### Edit/Update

From the comments I assume my initial question was a little to light, so let me explain *when* I see this failing, as it seems that my assumption of what the `ResponseEntity.HttpStatus` would be is correct.

I have made small adjustments to the code block above.
The situation where I receive an unexpected status is when I try to test the `NOT_FOUND` situation through Spring Cloud Contracts.

An example of the contract looks as follows:

```
Contract.make {
  request {
    method 'POST'
    url "/foo/SomeNoneExistingField"
    body("{}")
    headers {
      contentType applicationJson()
    }
  }
  response {
    status HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()
  }
}
```

So the `{some-field}` in this contract is set to a field which ensure that `doesNotExist({some-field}) == true`. I see it end up in this block if I am debugging my code as well.
Nonetheless, the Spring Cloud Contract test status that the `response.status == OK` i.o. `NOT_FOUND`.

Might I be using Spring Cloud Contracts incorrectly if my assumption on the `HttpStatus` returned from a `CompletableFuture` is correct?
Any help/advice is (again) much appreciated.

Comment: Your code will run as you expect it. The bit of code you gave is not sufficient to understand your problem. Do you have proper unit tests? It would be good if we could reproduce your problem, you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'll expand my use case a little, thanks for the response.

Comment: Are you using Spring Cloud Contract properly? Check this section of the docs to ensure that it's the case https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#_working_with_web_flux and here you have a sample https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/tree/master/producer_webflux

Comment: Thanks for that Marcin, I'll have a look asap.

Comment: I turned out to be a setting I had to add to my contracts if I was expected the result to be async...
It is described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.1.x/multi/multi__contract_dsl.html#_async_support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the issue I was experiencing.
Credits to [@Marcin Grzejszczak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877663/completablefutureresponseentity-status-code-expectations#comment90808886_51877663) for putting me on the right track in regards to configuration.

What I was missing from my contracts to be able to handle async results, like a `CompletableFuture`, was that I needed to add `async()` to my result.

Thus, a contract like so:

```
Contract.make {
  request {
    method 'POST'
    url "/foo/SomeNoneExistingField"
    body("{}")
    headers {
      contentType applicationJson()
    }
  }
  response {
    status HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()
    async() // <---- This was it!
  }
}
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing complex here and it should work as expected.

It is happening may be because of `{some-state}` is not true so every time it is going to else block.

Ensure that `{some-state}` evaluation returns `true` and compiler enters into `if` block.

```
if({some-state}) {
   return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Alien, I already thought my assumption was correct...
I have rephrased my question, as the issue I am encountering still holds whilst I am 100% certain it does end up in the if-block.
If you could find the time to check the updated questions for any guidance/help, that would be much appreciated.